# Jquery dynamically create content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

here is the extract of my code

```
 $("#temp").append('<div class="dynamic">' );
    $("#temp").append(a[i]);
    $("#temp").append("</div>");
```

this content is inside a for loop and dynamically add elements to div with id temp.

what i think it should produce is

```
<div id="temp">

.....
<div class="dynamic">
Education //value of a[i]
</div>
....


</div>
```

but what exactly it produces it

```
<div id="temp">

    <div class="dynamic"></div>

    Education
```

as confirmed from firebug. Because of which my css styling just breaks up.

Can you look into it?
Thank you

Comment: a is an array which i have created earlier in jquery code.

Answer (score 7):

Creating elements with jQuery should be done like this :

```
$('<div />', {'class': 'dynamic', text: a[i]}).appendTo('#temp');
```

Comment: @Wanna_be_Coder if you got correct solution then pick it as an answer

Comment: Why is `class` enclosed in quotes, but `text` is not? Can it be either way? Or is it just because `class` is a keyword? Any example of this syntax with slightly more complex markup, such as with additional child elements?

Comment: @JonathanWood - Yes, `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript, that's why it's quoted. Here's an example of something a little more complicated -> **http://jsfiddle.net/421qd4n7/1/**

Answer (score 0):

try this in loop, i guess your problem is solved...

```
var data = "<div class='dynamic'>" + a[i] + "</div>";
$("#temp").append(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var data = '<div class="dynamic">' + a[i] + '</div>';
$("#temp").append(data);
```

As when you append `$("#temp").append('<div class="dynamic">' );` a div is created and closed.

and when you append `$("#temp").append(a[i]);` it is appended after `div`